# How can I use Javascript to find a cookie with a random name?

Tags: javascript, regex

Wordpress sets several cookies with a random hash appended. How can I use Javascript (and regex?) to find out if a cookie named `wordpress_logged_in_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX` exists and what the name of it is?

[Picture.png http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/3453/pictureje.png](http://img9.imageshack.us/img9/3453/pictureje.png)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`document.cookie` is a string which contains all cookies, **excluding the HTTP-only** cookies.

To get any cookie which matches `wordpress_logged_in_....`, use:

```
document.cookie.match(/wordpress_logged_in_[a-z0-9]{32}=([^;]+)/)[1];
```

Explanation of pattern:

```
wordpress_logged_in_  # literally
[a-z0-9]{32}          # This fragment appears to be a md5 hash
=                     # literal =, separates a cookie key from its value
([^;]+)               # Create a group, containing all consecutive non-; chars
                      # ; marks the end of a cookie key-value pair.
```

Comment: Are the HTTP-only cookies excluded, or just their values? (I thought the [HTTPOnly] attributes -- would imply also a name? -- were still exposed.)

Comment: If the feature is well-implemented (which is the case in all decent browsers, including IE), the cookie cannot be read through JavaScript. See also: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly#What_is_HttpOnly.3F

Comment: +1 @pst - good comment, and you're right, these are HTTP only. Didn't realize that at first. +1/+1 @ Rob W - good answer and good comment.

Comment: if you want to test if user logged in from cookie please see my answer here: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/69814/check-if-user-is-logged-in-using-jquery/298840#298840